# How long should I wait after salary negotiation email?

Tags: salary, job-offer, new-job, negotiation, email

I got my first job offer, but they offered me a very low salary that is going to make it hard for me to even pay rent and transportation.

I sent an email negotiating for a higher salary, and it has been 2 working days with no response.  How long should I wait? I really don't want them to change their mind, especially that I don't have any other job offer.

Answer (score 7):

> How long should I wait?

I would suggest depending on what day of the week you begin the negotiations to be **patient and wait anywhere from 3-7 business days**.  If you start negotiating on Wednesday, it may push further into the following week as most decision maker's are hammered from a scheduling perspective on Monday's.

Also, you need to factor in **how much more** you are asking for (*more time off, more cash, etc. as it all has a cost*).   This amount may surpass what the immediate hiring manager is able to do without further approvals.  This could add several additional days to the process due to travel, vacations, sickness, etc.  In other words don't have a hard and fast timeline in your head.  *Be patient.*

On the flip side, if your only asking for a small additional concessions, then I would expect this to be handled **typically** in a couple of days.

In short, the **further apart** you are in the negotiations, the longer you should expect them to take.

[The negotiation process, a good read.](http://glassdoor.com/blog/how-to-handle-salary-counter-offer)

Answer (score 1):

One week is typical for follow ups.  Any more frequent and you might be seen as a pest, any less, and you may be seen as disinterested.  One week is customary.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend waiting at least a week before sending them a 'friendly reminder'.

Sending them an email soon after the initial email might seem that you are desperate. That won't well for you. On the other hand, not sending a reminder/follow-up email might show that you are either scared of approaching them, or you are too casual with the issue.

I wanted to know one thing from you situation, did they offer you the position during the interview, or some days after the interview via phone call? I am asking this because, if they offered you the position during the interview/face-to-face, then you should have negotiated the salary then and there itself. You shouldn't have delayed it. But this depends on when you were given job confirmation.

Source: Personal experience